# Postfix SMTP authentication

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp, dovecot, debian-wheezy

I used this guide to create a mailserver for a small business: https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy. IMAP is working perfectly but i ran into an issue with SMTP and Authenticated SMTP. When i use an email client (Inky, Airmail) i got logs from the IMAP connections but nothing from SMTP. The weirdest thing is that if u use my cell service on my phone it works...

My Postfix main.cf

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = webmail.voxel-it.com, voxel-it.com, localhost.voxel-it, localhost
myhostname = webmail.voxel-it.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = voxel-it.com
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client     blackholes.easynet.nl, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname,     reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks,     permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain,     reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = voxel-it.com
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender,                       reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/startssl-ca-bundle.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mailserver.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mailserver.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Someone with the same problem as me https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy/authenticated-smtp/#comment-2995

Comment: What error message do you get from the client?

Comment: @JennyD The only thing Airmail says is: STMP-test failed, A stable connection to the server could not be established.

Comment: What kind of network are you on when the connection doesn't work?

Comment: @JennyD My home network, and right now trying it on a different location same problem. I find it very weird that it would only allow me to send mails on a cell connection.

Comment: Are you using port 25 or 587?

Comment: @JennyD port 25 just edited my original post with the link to someone who has, what appears to be the same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add permit_sasl_authenticated to smtpd_client_restrictions and see whether it works.

Comment: Given that it works when they're using another network, I'd say this is unlikely to be the answer.

Comment: @eranga just tried it, same problem

Comment: @JennyD Thought the same. but again thought trying won't hurt. Also I can't comment yet so no way to suggest than giving this as an answer. Sorry.

Comment: @YoshiPeters looking at the thread you linked I might have another opinion. enable submission from master.cf and try connecting with port 587. your ISP may be blocking port 25.

Comment: @eranga I uncommented  this line "smtps inet n - - - - smtpd" and "submission inet n - - - - smtpd". That did the trick! I can send emails but when i try to send an email to a hosted email adress i get: "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table" But is is prop an other problem.